# OCFS2/GFS2 dlm_join_lockspace no fence domain

Tags: fedora, pacemaker, ocfs2, gfs2, cman

Ripping my hair out on a new Pacemaker/cman/(OCFS2|GFS) config.  I can't use the Pacemaker integration with OCFS2, since the Fedora team, in their wisdom, decided to remove the .pcmk.

Supposedly, I don't need to configure fencing in /etc/cluster/cluster.conf (the cman part, of course), and Pacemaker manages things fine if I have o2cb's cluster personality set to o2cb (rather than pcmk, which is unusable, or cman), but I lose fcntl() that way, whereas cman supports it.

o2cb/OCFS think they're running fine under cman, and the control daemons are brought up properly, but I'm unable to mount anything (which works fine with the volumes/o2cb tuned to o2cb as the cluster manager). OCFS2 volumes and GFS2 volumes (just to test them) both bomb out with something akin to:

> dlm_join_lockspace no fence domain

STONITH is configured in Pacemaker, fenced is running (with no errors in the logfile there), and everything seems peachy.  Except I can't get cluster filesystems to mount.

Comment: Is `cman` running? Did you get this error from the `corosync.log`? How about the other log files: `dlm_controld.log`, `gfs_controld.log`, ... Which command did you use to mount? Post all the relate configuration files?

Comment: first of all, cluster software version and your cluster.conf and fence_tool dump